# Optimized Linq querying?

Tags: c#, linq, csv

I'm trying to get the name of the student who has the highest GPA from a CSV data file containing: **ID**, **Name**, **Subject**, and **Scores**. I was able to solve my request, but I'm wondering whether there's a better way of doing this. I'm pretty sure there is, but I'm new to LINQ and would like to see what your suggestions are.

I have the data file available [here](https://github.com/ram302/StudentAverages/blob/master/scores.csv).

I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;



public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        const string fileName = @"c:\temp\scores.csv";
        String[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

        var studentData = from l in lines
                        // Skip header row.
                        .Skip(1)
                        // Split by comma.
                        let x = l.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                        // Parsed out into fields.
                        select new
                        {
                            ID = Convert.ToInt32(x.ElementAt(0))
                            , Name = x.ElementAt(1)
                            , Subject = x.ElementAt(2)
                            , Grade = Convert.ToInt32(x.ElementAt(3))
                        };

        var studentAvgRank = from b in studentData
                        // Grouping by name.
                        .GroupBy(g => g.Name)
                        // Interested in the averages for each students total scores.
                        .Select(g => new
                        {
                            Name = g.Key
                            , Avg = g.Average(c => c.Grade)
                        })
                        // In descending order.
                        orderby b.Avg descending
                        // We're only interested in the name, but just in case we can get the average too.
                        select b;

        // Output only the name of the highest average student, so select name of first entry in sorted list.
        Console.WriteLine(studentAvgRank.First().Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use linq to read csv, use a csv reader. Then maybe you could use linq with that reader if it supports it.

Comment: Try to use `index` instead of `ElementAt()` =>
`ID = Convert.ToInt32(x[0])
, Name = x[1]
, Subject = x[2]
, Grade = Convert.ToInt32(x[3])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thinking your meaning of "Optimized Linq Querying" is more about having neater looking code than actual run time optimization.

Here is some code I wrote to simplify the querying of the top student.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\...\scores.csv")
        .ToList();

    var scores = lines.Skip(1)
        .Select(l =>
        {
            var split = l.Split(',');
            return new { student = split[1].Trim(),
                score = Int32.Parse(split[3].Trim()) };
        });

    var orderedStudents = scores.GroupBy(s => s.student)
        .OrderByDescending(g => g.Average(s => s.score));

    var topStudent = orderedStudents.First();
    Console.WriteLine("{0} has the top scores with {1}", 
        topStudent.Key, topStudent.Average(s => s.score));

    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's right. I was looking for a cleaner way of accomplishing the same, that was perhaps more 'standard' way of doing this. Thanks!

Comment: FYI, I didn't really look very closely at the code you provided. Now that I looked at it, yours was pretty similar in concept. The main difference being you were using LINQ's 'query syntax' and I used 'method syntax'.

Answer (score 1):

Use [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) instead of linq, it is much faster than linq. You can use linq with that library to perform your operations.
For I/O operations one should avoid using linq and use readers.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thanks for this, but I should have added that I wanted to insist on using Linq, and my question should have asked for a more 'standard' approach to solving my problem using LINQ, and not an optimized solution per se.

Answer (score 1):

The most time-consuming part of your code is this part:

```
String[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
```

Instead, you can improve it by reading the file lines in parallel,
nowaday every normal PC supports parallel IO.

To read the file in parallel you may use `Parallel.ForEach` and to maintain the list of students you may use `ConcurrentQueue`. After that, your current linq query on that Queue should be fine (except that here you have to somehow prevent adding the first line in the queue).

The last thing is that maybe there are multiple students with the maximum average degree, hence the first or default is not a good option. Rather you can find the max GPA and then output everyone who has the max GPA.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I wanted to insist on keeping that part. I think I made my question confusing by asking for an 'optimized' solution, when I really mean a 'simpler/cleaner' approach to this problem.

Comment: @RudyM, clearly simpler cleaner is not really related to optimal, also your accepted answer is just a different format of your code. Not really cleaner.